# Upgrade-grub and boot-repair fails. Unable to boot one of my Linux systems, is there a way around?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have three Linux and two Windows systems on one computer.

After updating the kernel on one (archlinux) and running update-grub on the default (BIOS) boot disk (Xubuntu 12.04), the boot menu does not report the archlinux system.

After running boot-repair, I cannot boot the archlinux system by selecting it as the boot disk in BIOS because it now uses the boot configuration on the Xubuntu system instead of booting directly from its disk.

I really need to be able to boot the archlinux system, how can I do this?

Note: Bugs filed and notices made on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10.04 Ubuntu and the 12.04 Xubuntu `grub2` failed for different reasons, so I used the third Linux system to solve the problem, see [os-prober fails to identify a linux system so I need to write a custom grub2 menu entry as a workaround, how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165722/os-prober-fails-to-identify-a-linux-system-so-i-need-to-write-a-custom-grub2-men) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with Super GRUB 2 disk.

You can download it from [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)

Then install it in a usb using [Unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/)
Now you could restart your system and make sure it is set in the boot option menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/09_custom_arch
```

Put the following text in the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Arch Linux" {
insmod ext2
set root=(hd0,1)
linux /vmlinuz26  root=/dev/sda2 ro quiet rootdelay=1
initrd /kernel26.img
}
```

Be **sure** to modify the `(hd0,1)` and `sda2` to reflect the actual partition that contains Arch Linux in your particular setup.

Now, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should at the very least steer you in the correct direction.

*[Credits](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=108442)*

Comment: This looks like a good work-around, but I cannot get it to work or find any documentation that I can use.  One of the problem is that the disk is sometime sda and other times is sdg.  I'm going to ask another question.  (I wish I had backed up the grub.cfg from when it did work :( )

Comment: Although this will probably work for others, it doesn't on my hardware because the BIOS mixes up the hard-drive order from boot to boot.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a little app for linux, that has helped me greatly in getting my system to run correctly. (Windows dedicated drive + Linux also on a dedicated drive,) try this program: "Grub Customizer" after using the "Boot-Repair" (either disk, or installed via a PPA,) to manage the boot options.

I install each OS on it's own DRIVE (either HDD or USB,) and use the "F9" feature in my BIOS as I start to select which drive I want to load.

Using these two (2) programs together (Boot-Repair first, then Grub Customizer second,) has fixed my annoying troubles so that now when I start my computer, it starts as it is supposed to do. (Internal SSD first, has Windows 7 on it, F9 at boot to select other OS if I need.)

Hope this helps, I know the feeling of not having what you want, when it pertains to a running system. Before I go, one other very handy tool to use is: "TWEAK TOOL" not only to change fonts, resize background photo's for the desktop, but many useful hidden settings revealed with easy GUI buttons to select intended options.

Best of luck!